# How to return result in JSON format using a python update method

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I recently created an update method that changes the value of a key labeled age_upon_outcome in a Mongo database. It successfully updates the data in my database, but instead of returning a dictionary in JSON format, it returns a cursor. How can return the data in JSON format instead of cursor? Here is my code:

testing_script.ipynb

```
    from animal_shelter import AnimalShelter
    # now need to create the object from the class
    shelter = AnimalShelter("aacuser","Superman")
    data = {"age_upon_outcome":"2 years","animal_type":"Dog","breed":"Dachshund","color":"Black and  tan","name":"Rhonda","outcome_subtype":"Partner","outcome_type":"Adopt","sex_upon_outcome":"Female"}
    new_values = {"$set": {"age_upon_outcome":"3 years"}}

    # if shelter.create(data):
    #    print("Animal added")
    # else:
    #     print("Failed to add animal")
    
    # Calls the read function
    # shelter.read(data)

    # Calls the update function
    shelter.update(data, new_values)
```

output

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor at 0x7fb32a753f60>
```

animal_shelter.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class AnimalShelter(object):
    """ CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """

    def __init__(self,username,password):
        # Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to 
        # access the MongoDB databases and collections. 
        # init to connect to mongodb without authentication
        self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:55996')
        # init connect to mongodb with authentication
        # self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:55996/?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=AAC'%(username, password))
        self.database = self.client['AAC']

# Complete this create method to implement the C in CRUD.
    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            self.database.animals.insert(data)  # data should be dictionary  
            return True # Tells whether the create function ran successfully
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to save ...")

# Create method to implement the R in CRUD.     
    def read(self, data):
        return self.database.animals.find_one(data) #returns only one

# Update method to implement the U in CRUD.
    def update(self, data, new_values):
        if self.database.animals.count(data):
            self.database.animals.update(data, new_values)
            return self.database.animals.find({"age_upon_outcome":"3 years"})
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to update ...")
```

I have tried using this code within the update method:

```
return self.database.animals.find_one(data)
```

I was expecting an updated dictionary, but it just returns the original dictionary.

Comment: `cursor.toArray()` will pull the contents as a list.

Comment: The [`pymongo` tutorial](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) and other documentation demonstrates how to retrieve information from the MongoDB server.